# Input field disappears, input text stays

Tags: javascript, input

[Example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrhab.png)

Excuse my noobness.

- I want an input field that disappears when there's been input. (Like the '3' in the example.)
- I want the input field to return if I want to edit the input.

I've looked up online on how to do this and how to go around it, but I don't get anything useful out of it.

I have tried something like this (old, irrelevant code, it's just an example of what I tried to do):

```
function addButtonActions() {
    questionsButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var page = document.getElementById('page-questions');
        hideAllPages();

        page.style.display = 'block';
});

function hideAllPages() {
    var startPage = document.getElementById('page-start');
    var questionsPage = document.getElementById('page-questions');
    var scorePage = document.getElementById('page-score');

    startPage.style.display = 'none';   
    questionsPage.style.display = 'none';
    scorePage.style.display = 'none';
}
```

But it didn't seem to work for the input field.
I don't use `<form></form>`, because that always seems to give me bugs. Something like `<form></form>` doesn't help my layout for the page anyway, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: [Example of using FORM](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)

Your problem is in the JavaScript.  Your calling hide, then behind it calling BLOCK which unhides it.

```
hideAllPages();
page.style.display = 'block';
```

Also, what is questionsButton?  That needs to be an object variable.